# Decode a base64 document in ExpressJS response

Tags: node.js, file, express, base64

I would like to store some documents in a database as base64 strings. Then when those docs are requested using HTTP, I would like ExpressJS to decode the base64 docs and return them. So something like this:

```
app.get('/base64', function (req, res) {
    //pdf is my base64 encoded string that represents a document
    var buffer = new Buffer(pdf, 'base64');
    res.send(buffer);
});
```

The code is simply to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Do I need to use a stream for this? If so, how would I do that? Or should I be writing these docs to a temp directory and then serving up the file? Would be nice to skip that step if possible. Thanks!

UPDATE: Just to be clear I would like this to work with a typical HTTP request. So the user will click a link in his browser that will take him to a URL that returns a file from the database. Seems like it must be possible, Microsoft SharePoint stores serialized files in a SQL database and returns those files over http requests, and I don't believe it writes all those files to a temp location first. I'm feeling like a nodejs stream may be the answer, but I'm not very familiar with streaming.

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue? any problems?

Answer (score 2):

Before saving a file representation to the DB you can just use the toString method with base 64 encoding:

```
var base64pdf = pdf.toString('base64');
```

After you get the base64 file representation from db use the buffer as follows in order to convert it back to a file:

```
var decodedFile = new Buffer(base64pdf, 'base64');
```

More information on Buffer usages can be found here - [NodeJS Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding)

As for how to send a buffer from express server to the client, Socket IO should solve this issue.
Using socket.emit - 
Emits an event to the socket identified by the string name. Any
other parameters can be included.

> All datastructures are supported, including Buffer. JavaScript
>   functions can’t be serialized/deserialized.

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
});
```

Required documentation on [socket.io website.](http://socket.io/docs/)

Comment: Sure I understand that, but can I then send that file in the Express response? Or do I have to save the file to the server first and then issue the response?

Comment: In the question you sent the buffer as part of the response without saving it to server didn't you? This way you don't need to save it on the server.

Comment: The example in my question doesn't actually work, I was just giving an example. The only way I've been able to make it work was by saving the file to the server first using a Buffer. Then sending a link to the file in the response, then deleting the file.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt understand your entire question, I will look into it asap

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know socket.io supported Buffers. I'm actually already using it in this project. I'll try it out and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I hope my answer helped to solve your issue!

Comment: The more I think about this I'm not sure how it would work. I would like the client to make an HTTP request to the server and then have the file returned. With Socket.io the client makes a socket request, then the server can respond with emit. But I don't have an originating socket request from the client. I'll update my question to be a little more clear.

Comment: When the server sends the file you want the client user download it to his computer right?